How can I check whether an Outlook Add-in is running in a pop-out?
I am developing an Outlook Add-in using Typescript and Microsoft EWS. My Add-in runs in the right side panel of two locations:

The Inbox
Email-specific pop-outs (e.g. when a user double-clicks on an email so the email pops out into its own window).

I want to add a new functionality which only runs in the Inbox. So, how can I use EWS (or another Typescript approach) to configure my Add-in to check/know when it is running in the Inbox versus when it is running in a pop-out?
I've tried creating ExtensionPoint-specific URLs and checking the active URL (as recommended in the post In an Outlook addin, how to check whether we are in compose mode or read mode?) but both the Inbox and the pop-out seem to run in the same ExtensionPoint (so this has not helped me to differentiate between the two locations)
